# fltk set Fl_File_Chooser's Fl_File_Browser's selection_color

Tags: fltk

I am using fltk 1.3.2.

I couldn't find the way `Fl_File_Chooser`'s `Fl_File_Browser`'s `selection_color` but I needed it.

I looked at the codes of `Fl_File_Chooser` to inherit for my custom file chooser but the fileList item (type `Fl_File_Browser`) is in private part of the class.

I don't understand why fltk developers put the items in private part instead of protected part. If they put them in protected part we can inherit and add custom functions.

I had to edit library files. There was no other way I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply put a function that is named setFileBrowserSelectionColor in Fl_File_Chooser.H's public part.

```
class FL_EXPORT Fl_File_Chooser {
public:
...
  void setFileBrowserSelectionColor(Fl_Color color) {
    fileList->selection_color(color);
  }
...
```